# Postgresql partial index exceeds maximum index row size

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am trying to create a partial index to speed up full text search in my postgresql database.

```
CREATE INDEX book_search_not_null_index ON books(description) WHERE description IS NOT NULL;
```

I am getting the following error when trying to create my index:

```
index row requires 16016 bytes, maximum size is 8191
```

Some of the descriptions are quite long and are exceeding the row limit for my index. All I want from my index though is to make sure that I am not considering books with no description in my search (roughly 10% of the descriptions are null). Is there any way around this restriction or a better way to structure this index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GIN indexes for full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX)

```
create index book_search_not_null_index ON books 
using GIN (to_tsvector('english', description))
where description is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm actually using an index for the tsvector right now, but the tsvector is null if the description is, and I would like to exclude those rows from the search. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: @user1023465: Edited `where...`